# How to change icon on core-collapse toggle in polymer ?

Tags: polymer

Is there any way to change polymer `core-icon` on `core-collapse` collapse  without using jquery ?

This is my code

```
  <template repeat="{{contacts}}">
                <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="page-holder contact-dropdown dropdown-holder " horizontal layout center center-justified
                     on-tap="{{toggle}}" ident="{{cardID}}">
                    <div><img  src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80"></div>
                    <div flex style="margin-left:15px;">
                        <p class="user-name">Name</p>

                        <p class="user-dropdown-info">City <span class="blue bold"
                                                                   style="margin-right:15px;">City</span> nr <span
                                class="red bold">297493</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div> <core-icon style="margin-left:-10px;"  ident="{{oldIcon}}"  class="down-icon" icon="arrow-drop-down"></core-icon>
                        <core-icon style="margin-left:-10px;display: none;  "  ident="{{newIcon}}"  class="down-icon" icon="arrow-drop-up"></core-icon></div>


                </div>
                <div class="page-holder dropdown-holder" horizontal layout center center-justified>
                  <core-collapse class="collapse-content" id="{{cardID}}">
                        <div class="page-holder page-border" horizontal layout center center-justified>
                            <div>
                                <core-icon class="dropdown-icon collapsed-holder" icon="fa:phone"></core-icon>
                            </div>
                            <div flex><p class="text-dropdown">Call</p></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="page-holder page-border " horizontal layout center center-justified>
                            <div>
                                <core-icon  class="dropdown-icon collapsed-holder" icon="fa:envelope"></core-icon>
                            </div>
                            <div flex><p class="text-dropdown">Send e-mail</p></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="page-holder page-border" horizontal layout center center-justified>
                            <div>
                                <core-icon  class="dropdown-icon collapsed-holder" icon="fa:mobile"></core-icon>
                            </div>
                            <div flex><p class="text-dropdown">Send Msg</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </core-collapse>
                </div>
              </template>
```

I've tried to trigger function in `toggle` function , but i don't think it's good idea because firebug console returns null as `Icon` variable.

```
      IconClick: function(event, detail, sender) {
          var Icon=   this.getElementsByClassName('down-icon')[0];
          Icon.toggle();
        },
        toggle: function (e, detail, sender) {
            this.IconClick();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most "polymery" way to achieve what you want to do is by relying on data-binding without any extra code, binding to the `opened` attribute of the `core-collapse` element and hiding the icons using the `hidden` layout attribute with conditional binding.

Minimal sample:

```
<template>
  <core-icon hidden?="{{opened}}" icon="arrow-drop-down" on-click="{{toggle}}"></core-icon>
  <core-icon hidden?="{{!opened}}" icon="arrow-drop-up" on-click="{{toggle}}"></core-icon>
  <core-collapse id="collapse" opened="{{opened}}"><div>Content</div></core-collapse>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    toggle: function () {
      this.$.collapse.toggle();
    }      
  });
</script>
```

The reason why `this.getElementsByClassName` returns nothing is because you are querying the element's light DOM, but your elements are in the shadow DOM, so you would have to use `this.shadowRoot.getElementsByClassName` instead.